# Obtain PGP Signature inside the Commit

Tags: c#, libgit2sharp

Is there a way I can access the PGP signature embedded inside the commit using `libgit2sharp`?

I'm basically trying to achieve something similar to the `git log --show-signature` command.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So, it's basically as simple as:

```
using var repo = new Repository("");
var signature = Commit.ExtractSignature(repo, repo.Head.Tip.Id);
```